# Facebook Connect Cookie/Session issue

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

I am using the following 2 API's to create a facebook connect but having issues with the sessions being picked up the the PHP SDK. I have downloaded the latest facebook-connect-js & facebook-php-sdk

Here is my initial FB.init connect using the JS no problem ie.

```
<script>
  // initialize the library with the API key
  FB.init({
      apiKey: '9999999999999999999999999999',
      session : <?php echo json_encode($session); ?>,
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  $('#login').bind('click', function() {
      FB.login(handleSessionResponse);
  });
```

I can test if its working by reloading the page an using the following script I can see the response session.

```
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
      console.log(response.session)
    } else {
      // no user session available, someone you dont know
    }
  });
```

But the PHP SDK is not picking up the session.

ie

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '9999999999999999',
  'secret' => '9999999999999999999999999999999',
  'cookie' => true,
));

    $session = $facebook->getSession();
```

The javascript is creating a cookie but its not being found by the session.

Any suggestions to what I am doing wrong.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Have you checked your callback url?  It needs to point back to where it came from so your server knows to create the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason the problem has resolved itself.

May have been a server issue

Comment: Do you have any idea how it was resolved? I'm having a very similar issue.